# After exit Suspend Laptop turns every time back to suspend

Tags: 22.04, suspend, surface

I am running Ubuntu 22.04 LTS (Kernel: 5.15.0-58) on my Surface Pro 2. every time I close the lid (put it in suspend mode) and open it again later i.e. turn off suspend mode, it goes back to suspend mode after 30 seconds. Thanks in advance for the answers.

Comment: Try switching to the `linux-surface` kernel. https://github.com/linux-surface/linux-surface/wiki/Installation-and-Setup#debian--ubuntu

Comment: unfortunately this did not work but thanks anyway

Comment: try alternative ways to suspend.
   'systemctl suspend'
 using pm-utils     ' sudo pm-suspend'

sudo apt install pm-utils hibernate uswsusp